# Images not visible on live site work fine on local

Tags: wordpress, image, css

I am working on an e-commerce [site](https://vegan.zavoon.com/) and the product images are NOT visible on the live site but they are visible on my local development version even though I am using an exact copy of the code and database. What is even weirder is that when I open the developer console and look at 
 - the source code for the images is there and also the preview of the image is correct which tells me that the image is loaded correctly it must be something else.

Also, the only difference between the development site and the live site is that the live site runs on SSL, so I guess the problem could be related to that but I have no idea what it could be - the image urls start with `https`.

[Here](https://vegan.zavoon.com/product/saucony-originals-mens-jazz-low-pro-vegan-sneaker/) is an example page where the images are not visible.

Also, to mention the website is build with WordPress and WooComerce, custom theme.

**EDIT**: For some reason the images are no longer visible on the local version as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the parent elements / ancestors of the image (in single product view) is a DIV which has the `class` attribute `woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 images` and a `style` attribute which contains `opacity: 0`, i.e. completely transparent, therefore it remains invisible

So you have to find where that opacity setting is added and deactivate it. (Or if it's static, simply remove it from the HTML tag)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Problem now is why that is so.